# Rails - Acts as Nested - Impossible move, target node cannot be inside moved tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested

I'm using the Awesome Nested Set plugin: https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set

And in my model I do the following:

```
 acts_as_nested_set
 after_save :ensure_max_nestedset_level
private

def ensure_max_nestedset_level 
  if self.level > 2
    self.move_to_child_of(parent.parent)
  end
end
```

I do this to keep the levels from getting to deep. Any idea why I'm getting this "Impossible move, target node cannot be inside moved tree." error? What's strange is it happens on production but I can't replicate it on Dev.

Thanks

Comment: This happens to me as well with awesome_nested_set. I am using Heroku on cedar stack rails 3.2

Answer (score 9):

awesome_nested_set is used to store hierarchical data structure in relation database.
here are amazing article how we can store tree structure in database

http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/
http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

awesome_nested_set also use same technique for storing tree structure in database,and in tree there should not a cyclic relation!!

So
Make sure! there are no cyclic parent child relationship between nodes. awesome_nested_set check if this move can create cyclic relation it will throw exception `"Impossible move, target node cannot be inside moved tree."`

Example

```
 Food
    |\ Fruit 
    | |\Red
    | |   \Cherry 
    | |\Yellow 
    | | \Banana
    |\Meat
    | |\Beef
      |\Pork
```

Now in this tree you can move whole `Fruit` tree in child of `Meet` node But you can't move `Fruit` Node in any child of `Fruit` because it will make a cyclic relation and it will be impossible to iterate  over tree.

Now lets comeback to your question

1-I do this to keep the levels from getting to deep
 You don't need to worry about levels of tree as `awesome_nested_set` can load whole subtree in a single sql query see Link 1 how he dose it

2- Any idea why I'm getting this "Impossible move.." error
 Already have explain why you are getting this error. You can prevent this error to occur by before moving any move check if this move is valid by using

`move_possible?`

Answer (score 5):

This issue can appear because of `nil`  `lft` and `rgt` fields in database.

Try running

```
Model.rebuild!
```

in your `rails c`
This will recalculate all values related to `awesome_nested_set`.

Comment: This could be also due to having an invalid parent that prevents proper lft and rgt being calculated during Model.rebuild! , so removing those entries from the table will also help.

Answer (score 2):

we have a column in our database name parent_id, check it is not nil for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your data may be corrupt.

Check that your lft values are all less than your rgt values.  I had this error occur trying to move a sibiling (which was already in the correct place) to the right of another node.  I was baffled until I noticed that the data was corrupted somehow.